# Why is the transformation semigroup regular?

Tags: group-theory, functions, semigroups

> Exercise from J.H.Howie:Why is the transformation semigroup regular?

Let $S$ be a set .By the transformation semigroup $T(S)$ we mean the set of all mappings from $S$ to $S$.

In order to show that it is regular we take any $f\in T(S)$ .We need to show that there exists a $g\in T(S)$ such that $f=fgf$.

I am unable to construct such a function.

Please give some hints.

Comment: I think you mean "Let $S$ be a set", not "Let $S$ be a semigroup". Let $f \in T(S)$ and let $a \in S$. If $a \in {\rm im}(f)$ then define $g(a)=b$ for any $b$ with $f(b)=a$. Otherwise define $g(a)$ to be anything you like, such as $g(a)=a$. (Of course the fact that you have to make a choice for $b$ means that this argument is using the Axiom of Choice.)

Comment: Edited it @DerekHolt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $S\neq\varnothing$ and let $t_0\in S$.

For $s\in\text{im}f$ define $g(s):=t$ where $t\in S$ denotes some (chosen) element that satisfies $f(t)=s$. The fact that $s\in\text{im}f$ guarantees that we such $t$ exists.

This can be done if the axiom of choice is accepted.

For $s\notin\text{im}f$ define $g(s):=t_0$.

Check yourself that we have $f=fgf$.

---

If $S=\varnothing$ then there is only one choice for $f$ and $g$ wich is the empty map, and we automatically have $f=fgf$. That's why the axiom of choice mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @ drhab: I think it is not working , If $f$ is not one-one. Because $g$ gives two images of a single element.

Comment: @Struggler Do you agree at least that $g$ a well-defined function?  I don't understand what you mean by "$g$ gives two images of a single element". No well-defined function $g$ does that. Tell me what goes wrong here: let $x\in S$ with $f(x)=s$. Then $s\in\text{im}f$ so $g(s)=t$ for some chosen $t$ that satisfies $f(t)=s$ then $f(g(f(x)))=f(g(s))=f(t)=s=f(x)$ as required. Nothing goes wrong, I would say.

Comment: @ drhab: If $f$ is not one-one map, then there exist $a_1, a_2, b \in S$ such that $f(a_1) = f(a_2) = b$ where $a_1 \neq a_2$, then $g(b) = a_1$ and $g(b) = a_2$, so $g$ is not well defined.

Comment: @Struggler No. Then you just **choose** one of the $a_i$ (as said).

Comment: That's why the axiom of choice is mentioned in my answer